# I need information about reports

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, backend, report, react-fullstack

I already made a book page with react js and the database is MongoDB, but now they are asking me to add dynamic reports, for example which is the book that users search for the most!

Where can I find information, videos where they explain how to do that?

search for videos on youtube but they don't show what it would be like with MongoDB

Could you also tell me what the word cable is so I can search for that information online?